# sql query in php using In operator

Tags: php, ajax

I've got an ajax call to a php file where I would like to execute a sql query using the IN operator and then return the results to the ajax call.

```
Ajax:

var results = 'mobile =' + concatResults;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calc.php",
        data: results,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

when I do console.log(concatResults) I get results in the format for example:

```
  '0742481565','088323543','0832454334'
```

Then in my php file the main code lines are:

```
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM query where mobile_no in (:mobile)";
$stmt = oci_parse ($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":mobile" , $mobile);

//Execute
oci_execute ($stmt);

$displayResults = "";
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            $displayResults .= $row['MOBILE_NO'];
    }
echo $displayResults;
```

However, it seems like the in operator does not work in the format of the input. Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php --- check Example #8

Comment: could you `var_dump($mobile);` please and show us the value?

Answer (score 0):

To work

```
$mobile
```

must be an array, like so:

```
$mobile = array(1, 2, 3, 4) OR $mobile = explode(",", $mobile)
```

Comment: but I pass an array like string to the php file as in the format as shown '0742481565','088323543','0832454334'